# Python 3.7 About PEP 484 multiple type how to explain it?

Tags: python-3.7, pep

```
def read_image(file):
    image = imread(file)
    return image
```

in this case, i acept file is a path or a image array, how can I annotations for file?

```
def read_image(file: str|array):
```

is that possible?

### Update

Now it works.

following @iggy12345

```
from typing import Union
def read_image(file: Union[str, list]):
    .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use a `union`
This allows you to specify that a parameter has multiple types, for example

```py
from typing import union

def read_image(file: union[str, list]):
  pass
```

for more information on using unions, see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types)